# Exporting a posed armature as a mesh to another blender

Tags: mesh

I would appreciate anyone's help with a nagging problem I have been trying to solve for quite a while.

I have posed a rigged armature in a specific pose whilst in pose mode and would like to export this posed model (i.e. the mesh of the posed model alone) to another blender file that contains a scene. This is a static scene - no animations are required.

For this project I thus do not need the rig. I just need the posed model as a mesh.

In earlier attempts I either did not manage to retain the changes or else failed in other ways.

Would really appreciate someone's assistance to enable me to proceed with my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert the model to a mesh, which will remove all modifiers, parenting, and such, then export the mesh.

- Select the mesh.
- Press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.
- Select *'Mesh from curve/meta/surf/text'*.
- Click 'File' -> 'Export'.

Comment: Thank you lots for your support Uncle Snail

Answer (score 2):

For everyone looking in 2022, there is an easier non-destructive method:

1. select the frame you want to be exported as mesh only
2. export and make sure only the object type mesh is active

[image]

Now you have a file with just the mesh in its pose.
I find it useful when working with Substance and posing it to make texturing easier. (eg. opening a creatures mouth)

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks a lot!